# how to create .exe file for windows application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, wpf

I developed a application in C# Visual Studio 2010. How can I make this an .exe file to distribute it?

Comment: How have you developed it? What problem are you actually having?

Comment: Not enough information to answer this question. Voting to close.

Comment: i want to create a set up file which should run and work in the end user system . even though he doesnot have visual studio

Comment: for that you have to create a setup project..

Comment: If you are asking about creating a setup project you should revise your question to reflect this.

Comment: Can you explain why you have WPF and asp.net in the same application? That's an unusual choice.

Comment: i didnt use asp.net but reviewers can easily understand the question is about .net

Answer (score 3):

When you build and run the project Visual STudio automatically creates the .exe File in the Bin Folder of your project.

Create a setup project for windows app by going to Projects -> Other Project Types -> Setup and Deployment and choose Setup Project.

After creating setup project.
1) Select solution explorer, right click solution file and select Add Existing Project and then add your project.
2) After adding your project to setup project select the application folder right click then select Add -> Project Output, a new window will open, select your project from the drop down list then select Primary Output in the below window and click OK.
3) Build the solution, It will generate a .msi file in the debug folder of your setup project.
In order to install this application, the client PC must have .Net Framwork installed

Comment: @Oded. Is there any other tool available for creating Windows application ? I don't know. He writes in its question that he has developed its application using C#.Net

Comment: You are assuming he was writing a windows application and in windows. I guess you have never heard of [mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page).

Comment: yeah, If he develop his application in mono then he should write in it's question.

Comment: I have edited my answer, read it.

Comment: Create a setup project for windows app by going to Projects -> Other Project Types -> Setup and Deployment and choose Setup Project.

After creating setup project.
1) Select solution explorer, right click solution file and select Add Existing Project and then add your project.

Comment: 2) After adding your project to setup project select the application folder right click then select Add -> Project Output, a new window will open, select your project from the drop down list then select Primary Output in the below window and click OK.
3) Build the solution, It will generate a .msi file in the debug folder of your setup project.
In order to install this application, the client PC must have .Net Framwork installed

Answer (score 2):

there is a c# compiler provided for free by microsoft.  This is only if you didn't use visual studio, in the case you used VS, follow the other solutions

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1700bbwd%28v=vs.71%29.aspx